# LNK2005 linkage error when running c++ unit test

Tags: c++, unit-testing

I am relatively new to c++ and I am not sure how I can resolve this error. I have a namespace `QueryUtils` which I am including it into another class `QuerySyntaxProcessing`. Below are the definitions for the following

QueryUtils.cpp

```
#pragma once
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

namespace QueryUtils
{
static const std::string SELECT_KEYWORD = "Select" + ' ';
static const std::string SUCHTHAT_KEYWORD = ' ' + "Such that";

size_t split(const std::string& txt, std::vector<std::string>& strs, char ch)
{
    size_t pos = txt.find(ch);
    size_t initialPos = 0;
    strs.clear();

    // Decompose statement
    while (pos != std::string::npos) {
        strs.push_back(txt.substr(initialPos, pos - initialPos));
        initialPos = pos + 1;

        pos = txt.find(ch, initialPos);
    }

    // Add the last one
    strs.push_back(txt.substr(initialPos, std::min(pos, txt.size()) - initialPos + 1));

    return strs.size();
}

std::string getStringBetween(const std::string& s, const std::string& start_delim, const std::string& stop_delim)
{
    unsigned first_delim_pos = s.find(start_delim);
    unsigned end_pos_of_first_delim = first_delim_pos + start_delim.length();
    unsigned last_delim_pos = s.find(stop_delim);

    return s.substr(end_pos_of_first_delim,
        last_delim_pos - end_pos_of_first_delim);
}
};
```

QuerySyntaxProcessing.cpp

```
#include "QuerySyntaxProcessing.h"
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include "QueryUtils.cpp"

QuerySyntaxProcessing::QuerySyntaxProcessing()
{
    entityMap["stmt"] = DesignEntities::NORMAL_STATEMENT;
    entityMap["variable"] = DesignEntities::VARIABLE; 
    designEntities = { "stmt", "read", "print", "call", "while", "if", "assign", "variable", "constant", "procedure" };
}

QuerySyntaxProcessing::~QuerySyntaxProcessing()
{
}
```

I am omitting more details in `QuerySyntaxProcessing.cpp` as the methods are too long. However, I am using the namespace methods of `QueryUtils` in the functions for this class. I do not get any errors when building the project.

QuerySyntaxTests.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include "QuerySyntaxProcessing.h"
using namespace Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework;

namespace UnitTesting
{
    TEST_CLASS(TestPQLSytnax)
    {
    public:

        TEST_METHOD(SynonymTest) {
            QuerySyntaxProcessing* queryProcessing = new QuerySyntaxProcessing();

            vector<string> multipleVars = { "v", "a", "cd" };
            vector<string> singleVars = { "hello" };
            vector<string> wrongVars = { "54v" };
            Assert::AreEqual(queryProcessing->isSynonym(multipleVars), true);
            Assert::AreEqual(queryProcessing->isSynonym(singleVars), true);
            Assert::AreEqual(queryProcessing->isSynonym(wrongVars), false);

        }

    };
}
```

When I try to build the unit tests for `QuerySyntaxProcessing.cpp`, I get an error LNK 2005.

The error message appears when even trying to initialize the constructor for `*QuerySyntaxProcessing` instance. I am not double including `QueryUtils.cpp` header in any of the other headers. So not very sure what is wrong.

`Error  LNK2005 "class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __cdecl QueryUtils::getStringBetween(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (?getStringBetween@QueryUtils@@YA?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@ABV23@00@Z) already defined in QueryUtilsTest.obj  UnitTesting C:\Users\yicho\team16-win-spa-19s2\Team00\Code00\UnitTest`ing\SPA.lib(QuerySyntaxProcessing.obj)    1

Thank you all for your help..

Comment: `QueryUtils.cpp` is not written as a header and should not be included anywhere.

Comment: then I should put my namespace implmentation in a .h file instead ?

Comment: @calveeen But remember, function *declarations* in the header file, and their *definitions* (implementation) is a source file. Unless you make the function `static` or `inline`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I see. So I have to create 2 files, one .h which contains the declarations for the namespace and a .cpp file for the implementations ? Where should i define the const static variables in that case ?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude hey i got it already thank you !

Answer (score 0):

In my case, you should't have the corresponding .cpp file for the unit test header. In your case, it's `QuerySyntaxProcessing.cpp`, you shouldn't have it. So all the implement should be written in the .h (It's not difficult with morden C++ standards).

I guess there are some global or static varibles defined in TEST_CLASS, TEST_METHOD or something like that.